# boost empty ptree as map in json

Tags: json, boost, tree

I am using boost ptree to create a json string here's my code :

```
int main()
{
    ptree pt;
    ptree commands;


    pt.put<int>("mCommandID", 1);
    pt.put<int>("mTimeSent", 0);
    pt.add_child("commands", commands);
    write_json(cout,pt);
}
```

but the output of this code is :

```
{
    "mCommandID": "1",
    "mTimeSent": "0",
    "commands": ""
}
```

and I like it to be :

```
{
    "mCommandID": "1",
    "mTimeSent": "0",
    "commands": "{}"
}
```

how is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want JSON inside JSON, so you want to write_json twice:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62a5a696eebfe12c)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::property_tree;

std::string to_json_string(ptree const& pt)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    json_parser::write_json(oss, pt, false);
    return oss.str();
}

int main()
{
    ptree pt;
    ptree commands;

    pt.put<int>("mCommandID", 1);
    pt.put<int>("mTimeSent", 0);
    pt.put("commands", to_json_string(ptree {}));
    pt.put("more-commands", to_json_string(pt)); // a crude example

    json_parser::write_json(std::cout, pt);
}
```

Prints

```
{
    "mCommandID": "1",
    "mTimeSent": "0",
    "commands": "{}\n",
    "more-commands": "{\"mCommandID\":\"1\",\"mTimeSent\":\"0\",\"commands\":\"{}\\n\"}\n"
}
```